# Python Code Introspection and Analysis

Tags: python, compiler-construction, interpreter, introspection

I am trying to write a Python code analyzer, and I am trying to avoid having to parse bare Python text files.  I was hoping that once the Python compiler/interpreter parses the code there's a way to get to the object code or parse tree from within a running Python program.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What is your purpose here? Are you writing a syntax highlighter? A Python interpreter? Something else?

Comment: Have you downloaded and read pylint?  Start with that as a good example of what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) and [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html) should provide the necessary framework for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [Python's abstract syntax trees](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html).